Concerning cracks in drywall
noticed this crack in a bedroom. I picked at the peeling paint and they are really thin hairline crack. The exterior side od this wall is brick and shows no sign of damage. The window operates normal and is level. Any thoughts? Do you think this is structural or is it more to do with the craftmanship/work?
https://imgur.com/a/sE3HAMU

Looks more like a bad paint prep job.  Peeling paint, maybe from dirt/dust/oil left on the wall or maybe moisture problems.

Could be a poorly taped drywall joint

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Knowing what is between the brick work and that painted surface would help.  Bricks are not good moisture vapour barriers.  The corner window trim looks like from an older time(before 60s/50s), so vapour barrier might not be the best.

47, good call. Yeah I think moisture may be an issue. Had a humidifier in there for a while too

A hairline crack in drywall you haven't personally repaired multiple times is unlikely to be a structural issue.
If you repair it and it's back next year, then get concerned. If it's wide, get concerned. If you can't see an issue with the structure it's probably cosmetic, and if it's not cosmetic, it will crack again after you repair it. Then go looking for the underlying issue.
Peeling paint usually indicates a moisture problem.

This is easy. Measure from the ceiling to the crack. If it's exactly 48", that means the crack is exactly at the joint. Two possible issues: (1) bad taping job (unlikely, if the crack is new), or (2) moisture building up behind the wall and coming through the gap between the two sheets of drywall. Seeing that you have peeling paint in other areas of the wall, my money is on #2.
If this were a structural issue, I'd expect the cracks to be diagonal and starting a the upper corners of the window trim and moving towards the ceiling. That's usually the first place where you see walls cracking when the foundation is moving.
